# Graphql bottleneck performance with nested query (Django + React ) makes frontend app unusable. Please help :'(

Tags: mysql, reactjs, django, graphql, graphene-python

For this project Im using Python+Django and GraphQL (graphene) in the backend, MySQL as database and React.js for the frontend.

In the frontend, after user logs in, I have the following query to be executed:

```
const GET_ORGANIZATION = gql`
query getOrganization($orgId : Int!) {
  organization(id:$orgId){
    id
    name
    user{
      id
      username
      firstName
      lastName
      email
      dateJoined
      lastLogin
      isActive
      trainings {
        id
        name
        sessions {
          id
          name
          category
          createdAt
          totalSteps
          completedAt
          user {
            id
          }
          eventSet {
            id
            category
            description
            object
            errorSeverity
            performedAt
          }
        }
      }
    }
    courses{
      id
      name
      description
      trainings{
        id
        name
        user{
          id
          username
          isSuperuser
          isStaff
          isActive
          email
        }
        sessions{
          id
          name
          category
          createdAt
          completedAt
          user{
            id
            username
          } 
          eventSet {
            id
            category
            description
            object
            errorSeverity
            performedAt
          }                 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`;
```

As you can see, it has several levels nested. The problem comes when I go into *sessions* and *events* . I am not super expert with graphQL but I always thought the selling idea of GraphQL was that you can use all these nested fields in one single query. Well, it's not. Here are few images why:

[image: It takes over 30 seconds for the response to come]

It takes over 30 seconds for the response to come. Digging a bit more into the slow_log of my database, I find this:

[image: MySQL slow_log]

The same query is repeated several times with the same paramaters:

[image: repeated query]

This is repeated over 5000 times.
Reading through on SO and other sources, it seems that this is the classical N+1 problem with GraphQL

So now I'm facing two roads of a (hopefully) solution :

1. First one, I find a way to make this query be usable the way it is, with the amount of data that there is, and here is where I need advice and help. Is there a way? I'd like to think so, because if a few levels of nesting and some thousands of rows in one of these levels is enough to make it unusable, then I guess nobody would be using it.
2. The second way, and that's the one I started doing today, but then stopped, cried and came to create this post: I limit my query to go only until trainings level, and instead of having one big query, I have several smaller ones. The problem with this approach that was the cause of my suffering is that I realized I'll basically have to redo my entire react components in the frontend, since many of them are expecting the data to be in that big object, not to mention when you pass that object or parts of it down to other components

Which one would you advise? Or is there any other way ?
Keep in mind, I have very very limited time to make big changes as a deadline approaches in the next few days for me to have this live.

*To add some context:*
I'm alone working on a sort of metric app that support a VR application. There's no team (frontend and devOps guy left as soon as I joined), so I have to do all the devOps, front and backend work which is a lot of work. Because of that pressure I did the rookie mistake of never taking the time to get a copy of the DB that contains all the data collected by the VR that will be in fact the data users will be visualizing on frontend. So I have always been testing with dummy smaller data and everything worked "perfectly" so far. May this be a lesson to myself and others reading this question/cry for help: make sure your environment is as close as possible to production when developing, specially having data enough

Comment: the possibility is not a must ... **you can query n levels deep data but you shouldn't** ... use query/data on components displaying it ... query list on list view, query details on detail view etc. ... basic knowledge

Comment: no, not basically knowledge. If I have to query the way you're saying, I'm basically using REST approach, where I have endpoints for different data I need. What's the point of adopting GraphQL then?

Comment: what's the point to still overfetching [as in REST] ?

Comment: it's not overfetching if I actually need all of that data in one place. Anyways, don't bother...I already solved my problem  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mark's answer, I looked around and found this package
https://github.com/tfoxy/graphene-django-optimizer that does exactly what he suggested.

Using it was easy enough. For example for optimizing my organization_resolver all I had to do was:

```
    def resolve_organization(root, info, id):
        return gql_optimizer.query(Organization.objects.filter(pk=id),info).get()
```

The query went from over 50s to 11s . Huge improvement!
[image]

Still, not quite as fast as I can, but there are other improvements I can still do.

And in their page, under **Advanced Usage** it explains how to do a few hacks for more complex resolvers

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone else who also faces the same issue

Comment: 11s still sounds terrible.

Comment: as I said, still other improvements to be done. The major bottleneck has been taken care

Comment: This fixed my problem sufficiently, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem with GraphQL per se, but a problem with graphene's implementation.  As you've discovered, there is no SQL query optimization, and queries are created for each level of depth, which gets ridiculously bad for deep GraphQL queries.

Some options that you have:

1. fix graphene's implementation by creating some sort of query optimizer for multiple levels of depth -- based on your analysis, you can see that it would be easy to make some improvements, and if you contributed to the open source project the community would be most appreciative (but this option would be months of work)
2. create your own resolvers that hijack parts of the query that are particularly slow and replace with your own optimized query that includes all necessary joins and returns structured JSON output
3. create custom fields and/or object types that aren't part of your Django schema and write optimized field resolvers as described above.
4. (UPDATE) look for a query optimizer (see @Rafael's answer for details)

Comment: thanks man. Your suggestions helped me a lot to find the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [DataLoader](https://github.com/syrusakbary/aiodataloader). instead of trying to hit the database every single time graphql resolves nested `graphql query`, we can batch the `database query` then hit the database once.

**example (in js since I don't understand python)**

**WITHOUT DATALOADER**

```
// the schema

type Query {
  user: User
  users: [User]
}

type User {
  id: String!
  email: String!
  name: String
  profile: Profile
}

type Profile {
  bio: String
  age: Int
  user: User
  userId: String
}
```

```js
// Resolver
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    user: (): null => null,
    users: async (_, __, context) => {
      return await context.db.user.findMany({})
    },
  },
  User: {
    profile: async (parent, _, context) => {
      return await context.db.profile.findFirst({
        where: {
          userId: parent.id,
        },
      })
    },
  },
  Profile: {
    user: async (parent, _, context) => {
      return await context.db.user.findFirst({
        where: {
          id: parent.userId
        }
      })
    },
  },
}
```

and the result when i try this graphql query

```
query {
  users {
    email
    name
    profile {
      bio
      user {
        email
      }
    }
  }
}
```

is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJlKe.png) (about hundred database queries or more)

**WITH DATALOADER**

```js
// Loader.js

async function profileBatchFunction(keys: readonly string[]) {
  const result = await db.profile.findMany({
    where: {
      userId: {
        in: keys as string[],
      },
    },
  })
  return keys.map(k => result.find(res => res.userId === k) || null)
}
export const profileLoader = new DataLoader(profileBatchFunction)

async function userBatchFunction(keys: readonly string[]) {
  const result = await db.user.findMany({
    where: {
      id: {
        in: keys as string[],
      },
    },
  })
  return keys.map(k => result.find(res => res.id === k) || null)
}
export const userLoader = new DataLoader(userBatchFunction)
```

```js
// Resolver
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    user: (): null => null,
    users: async (_, __, context) => {
      return await context.db.user.findMany({})
    },
  },
  Profile: {
    user: async parent => {
      return await userLoader.load(parent.userId)
    },
  },
  User: {
    profile: async parent => {
      return await profileLoader.load(parent.id)
    },
  },
}
```

and the result with the same `graphql query` is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wel3Q.png). much better